# How to reverse values in a string in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string

Using T-SQL, I'm trying to find the easiest way to make:

"abc.def.ghi/jkl" become "abc/def/ghi.jkl"?

Basically switch the . and /

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way

```
select replace(replace(replace('abc.def.ghi/jkl','/','-'),'.','/'),'-','.')
```

you need to use an intermediate step, I chose the - symbol, choose something which won't exist in your  string

Comment: +1, anyway he should replace '-' with a character that will never be in his input, in the case this is some general thing.

Comment: Nice. The intermediate step FTW! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REVERSE(@myvar) AS Reversed, 
RIGHT(@myVar, CHARINDEX(‘ ‘, REVERSE(@myvar))) as Lastname;
```

took the answer from this guys blog. The first google result. You will need to modify it for your needs

[link text](http://remicaron.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/tsql-getting-characters-from-the-rightside-of-the-string-using-charindex-and-reverse/)

Comment: No, the OP didn't mean "reverse", he meant "exchange". (but your reversing undoubtedly works)